# Site recommendation for questions about roads, public works, etc

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would be the best SE (if any) to ask a question about the features of public works? (like roads, bridge construction, etc)

Comment: What type of question about public works?  There are all sorts of things you might ask about them that could belong on different sites.

Comment: Q about physical features. Like why a portion of land or concrete might be built the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://engineering.stackexchange.com/.

It has questions tagged [roadway](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roadway), [bridges](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridges) and the more general tag [civil-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-engineering)